# How to get the list of ChangesetIDs in an iteration path from source control?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I want to get the list of changes (i.e. the ChangeSetID's) associated with an iteration path.
Is there  a way we can get the list of them ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you link your changesets to your work items!

There is no direct relationship between a check-in and an iteration except where it is created. When your developers check-in they get the option to relate their check-in to one or more work items within the work item tracking system. so:

Iteration -> Work Item -> Changeset

So in order to retrieve your list of changesets associated with your iteration you:

1. User the API to query for all work items where [System.Iteration] Under "[project]\Release 1\Sprint 1"
2. Loop through each work item returned and return all changeset links

I hope this helps you...

Code paraphrased:

**To get Work item Store**

```
_store = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

**To get Query Results**

```
_store.Query("SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project  AND  [System.IterationPath] UNDER 'TfsExtensions\TfsFieldAnnotate\Release 1' ORDER BY [System.Id] ")
```

Each work item then contains "wi.Links" and you should be able to find the Changeset Lin Type easily...